# Adding UITableViewController.view as subview behaving badly

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I am trying to animate a tableview into my view, however I cannot get the data in the UITableView to appear (NAConversationViewController below is a subclass of UITableViewController):

```
Post *post = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *takeover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
takeover.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.75];

NAConversationViewController *vc = [[NAConversationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NAConversationViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
vc.post = post;
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 320);

[takeover addSubview:vc.view];
[self.view addSubview:takeover];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations: ^{

                     vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 320);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         [vc.view setNeedsDisplay];
                     }
                 }];
```

The only way I can get the table data to show is [vc.view setNeedsDisplay]; but as soon as I scroll on the tableview the table cells instantly disappear.

Am I invoking the UITableView incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have your UITableViewController Delegate methods set appropriately in your NAConversationViewController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ARC, the NAConversationViewController instance is probably being released, and it's view too... Try creating an instance variable so the view controller does not get deallocated.